# why "Loading widget." message appears in JupyterLab?

Tags: annotations, widget, jupyter-lab

I got "Loading widget" message when I tried to run this cell .

```
foodfns = sorted(os.listdir('foods'))
targets = np.zeros((len(foodfns), 4), dtype='int') # (x,y,w,h) for each data row
Innotater( ImageInnotation(foodfns, path='foods'), BoundingBoxInnotation(targets) )
```

[Code with  Loading widget message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLphc.png)

Expected output : https://github.com/ideonate/jupyter-innotater

Answer (score 1):

in the Kaggle notebook, (2023-08-23), we solve this problem by using the new environment.

[image: kaggle environment]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed the libraries correctly, and also waited for the JupyterLab assets to rebuild. However, you would almost certainly need to at least reload the page at that point in order to pick up the latest Javascript that has just been rebuilt. (Maybe you did this.)

It might even be worth restarting the Jupyter server itself, and then also clearing browser cache and reloading.

To be honest, I've still not quite got to grips with JupyterLab's extension loading system - it doesn't work well for me either.

What version of JupyterLab are you using (2.0+ is recommended)?